# Passing an object using intent to multiple classes

Tags: java, android

Hi all I was wondering if is it possible to passing an object using intent to multiple classes.
I know of passing only to 1 class.

Class1

```
Intent intent = new Intent(class1.this, class2.this)
intent.putExtra("item", itemMain);
StartActivity(intent);
```

Class2

```
Bundle retrieveData = getIntent().getExtras().getString("item");
```

What I want to do is pass the original itemMain to all classes like class 3,4,5

Comment: I have an original data that needs to be modified and altered through different activities.

Comment: this 'data' that need to be modified, does it need to be altered even if user does not see that data at this exact moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just use SharedPreference like this..

Here is how to insert data into shared preference..

```
SharedPreferences app_preferences = 
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
 editor.putString("item", item);
 editor.commit(); //Very important part
```

Here is how to get the information in all classes...

```
 SharedPreferences app_preferences = 
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
 String item = app_preferences.getString("item", "No Item");
```

Comment: It seems like you are passing a String

Comment: it could be problematic if it is an object that has to be passed

Comment: =) glad to have helped. Its the easiest and most reliable way for making information available through out your application.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to have the object in question owned by the Application, not a specific Activity. Then all activities will have access to the object.